# Invalid argument foreach()

Tags: php, oop

I have the follow code, but, i get an error in my code. 
I cant find the problem but, I think it comes from: 
    UserManagement::findByUsername($username);

```
$a_allSections = UserManagement::findByUsername($username);
    if($a_allSections) 
    {
        foreach($a_allSections as $a_section)
        {
              echo $a_section['name'];?>
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
         echo 'There's nothing found.' . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: What type is your `$a_allSections` ?

Comment: a better check might be `if(is_array($a_allSections))`

Comment: @andreas, returned object can be an object containing iterator.

Comment: Also, not sure if typo, but I think it should be `echo "There's nothing found\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `$a_allSections` is not an array, so `foreach` complains. Use `var_dump($a_allSections)` to find out what exactly it is, and fix your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this way**

UserManagement::findByUsername($username);

1.the function findByUsername($username) should return some values

2.the class should be included in current document.

3.Check whether your return result as array. if array means check is_array();

4.if above 3 ok in your question then you will not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

$a_allSections may be empty

change condition to

```
    if(is_array($a_allSections)){
      ...
    }
```

to prevent such error on empty arrays

Comment: -1: He already has a check (`if($a_allSections)`) that [guarantees](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) the array (if it were an array) would not be empty. Even if it *was* an empty array, PHP would not give a warning for that.

Comment: what if that returns an object or some string or some integer? may be from some mistake in findByUsername method. if($a_allSections) don't check if its an array or not it just see if the variable in if condition have some value or not. makes sense?

Comment: Obviously the variable is not an array, otherwise this question would not have been asked. But the correct way to handle this is to find out *why* it's not an array, not put the code inside an `if` where it will never be executed.